# Erro ao retornar página com Curl + PHP

Tags: php, libcurl

Estou utilizando o `cUrl` + `PHP` para abrir um site externo, porém quando tento fazer isso ele até carrega normal mas não mostra a o conteúdo que estou precisando. No **console** do **Chrome** aparece esse erro abaixo e imagino que seja esse o motivo:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'domain' property on 'Document': 'siteexterno.com' is not a suffix of 'meudominio.com.br'.
```

Alguém sabe como posso resolver isso? Lembrando que não tenho acesso ao site externo.

**Código**

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://br.sportingbet.com/esportes-futebol/brasil-s%C3%A9rie-a/1-102-190183.html');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20041001 Firefox/0.10.1');
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $html;
```

**Atualização**

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://br.sportingbet.com/esportes-futebol/brasil-s%C3%A9rie-a/1-102-190183.html');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20041001 Firefox/0.10.1');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '217.70.67.34'); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, '8080');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, 'HTTP');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $html;
```

Comment: Acho que se colocar o código além do erro pode ajudar

Comment: Atualizei acima e inseri o código que utilizo para acessar o site, inclusive o site que estou tentando acessar.

Comment: qual o conteudo que quer que não está conseguindo acessar?

Comment: Se você abrir esse endereço por exemplo `https://br.sportingbet.com/esportes-futebol/brasil-s%C3%A9rie-a/1-102-190183.html` você vai ver ao centro da página os próximos jogos que irão acontecer, se você tentar acessar utilizando o `cUrl` não terá essa área a mostra.

Comment: Provavelmente pq deve haver um carregamento via ajax, pra fazer com CURL eu nunca fiz, use `phantomjs`...

Comment: Isso não tem nada haver com o cURL. Esse erro aparece porque está tentando carregar um conteúdo que não tem permissão. O HTML que obtem do cURL está tentando obter informações via AJAX e obviamente o seu domínio não está autorizado para pegar essa informação. Ou seja, você (seusite.com) está tentando pegar informações de `outrosite.com` e por CORS não conseguirá. A maneira de passar isso é justamente usando cURL, porém de maneira mais inteligente, você deve pegar todo o conteúdo via cURL.

Comment: @MagicHat Agora fiquei confuso, estou usando o cUrl para puxar o site, como faria isso com js?

Comment: @Inkeliz você está abrindo uma porta pra mim e isso é muito bom, mas quando você diz **maneira mais inteligente**  o que você se refere? Por acaso o DOMdocument é uma opção?

Comment: Brother,  já passei por isso e com cURL para mim foi difícil, então com phantomjs ficou fácil, se você domina e consegue simular os requests do Ajax os heders os cookies e tudo mais, dá para fazer com cURL, eu acho, mas eu nunca fiz... se o @Inkeliz puder dar umas dicas vai valer para mim também... vamos aguradar

Comment: Não dá para saber os objetivos que tem com o cURL. Em geral, o que precisará é usar o cURL como um proxy. O que você está fazendo é apenas pegando a página inicial. O que você pode fazer é usar o cURL como literalmente um proxy. A ideia é que quando o site solicitar uma requisição para `siteexterno.com/api/qlcoisa` você mude para `seusite.com/api/qlqrcoisa` e essa página chamará, via cURL, para `siteexterno.com/api/qlcoisa`. No final, o cliente chamará por uma pagina do seu site, nenhum erro será apresentado. E o seu site chamará internamente por um site externo, via cURL.

Comment: @Inkeliz não sei se estou pesquisando errado mas ainda sem sucesso

Comment: @Inkeliz coloquei acima o código conforme pesquisei, mas continua me dando a mesma coisa, o que você acha que pode ser?

Comment: Esses são os dados que deseja capturar? https://br.sportingbet.com/services/CouponTemplate.mvc/GetCoupon?couponAction=EVENTCLASSCOUPON&sportIds=102&marketTypeId=&eventId=&bookId=&eventClassId=190183&sportId=102&eventTimeGroup=ETG_NextFewHours_0_0

Comment: Isso mesmo, esses são os dados que preciso.

Comment: Izzas, izazas, isso isso isso... haha... Oh vou precisar sair, mas deixo uma dica em python, mas no fim verá que o level 3 é muitooo mais fácil... Boa Sorte;) http://docs.pyspider.org/en/latest/tutorial/AJAX-and-more-HTTP/  Para mim o melhor da programação é o "quebrar de cabeça", este tipo de coisa não dá para aprender com pressa... Se já quebrou a cuca bastante hj deixe para amanhâ..  Vou tentar fazer com cUrl e posto uma resposta....

Comment: Vlw pela luz, vou avançar aqui. Vlw!!

Comment: O que eu disse foi para usar o cURL *como* proxy e não usar um proxy no cURL, isso por si faz toda a diferença.

Comment: @Inkeliz realmente isso faz toda a diferença, mas não vou mentir que isso continua bugando minha cabeça kkkk

Comment: @Inkeliz você sugeriu isso por achar q seria possivel ou isso que você disse é algo possível?

Comment: É algo totalmente possível e não é nada "revolucionário". Pesquisando rapidamente, [tem isso](http://benalman.com/projects/php-simple-proxy/) e [isso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29837162/bypassing-cors-with-php-and-javascript-ajax), justamente a mesma ideia, e o mesmo nome de "proxy".